# In Rally .Net API : How to use Query.Operator.Contains with array or list(OR condition)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, rally

Using Rally ,Net API v2.0 with C#. I am trying to get an OR condition filter for my query so that I can pass in a list of IDs.

Something along the lines of:

```
  string input = "abc, xyz1";
  Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
  storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Contains, input);
```

I want to be able to add multiple IDs to the input list and have it work without having to write another OR in the query string.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The FormattedID attribute does not support the contains operator.  You'll have to OR together all the searches.

Comment: @PreethaA has OR worked for you? In my case it works for only two IDs